# Access operator from specific module in Swift

Tags: swift, operators

I've written a library to use a protocol that the Swift standard number types implement. I also added some operators, in this case `<`. Here is the code:

```
public func < (lhs: NumberConvertible, rhs: NumberConvertible) -> Bool {
    return lhs.toDouble() < rhs.toDouble()
}
/// Everything that is a number
public protocol NumberConvertible {
    // MARK: - floating points
    func toDouble() -> Double
    func toCGFloat() -> CGFloat
    func toFloat() -> Float

    // MARK: - signed integers
    func toInt8() -> Int8
    func toInt16() -> Int16
    func toInt32() -> Int32
    func toInt64() -> Int64
    func toInt() -> Int

    // MARK: - unsigned integers
    func toUInt8() -> UInt8
    func toUInt16() -> UInt16
    func toUInt32() -> UInt32
    func toUInt64() -> UInt64
    func toUInt() -> UInt

    init(_ number: NumberConvertible)
}
```

`Double` implements NumberConvertible, and it seems that `<` calls itself,`NumberConvertible` instead of `Double`. I want to use the standard `<` operator for `Double`, in the `Swift` module. Is that possible? If more code is needed, check [here](http://github.com/SpilledMango/MegaMath). I've tried `Swift.<` but that gives me a syntax error.

Comment: Why don't you just use the Decimal struct? https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/decimal/ It does conforms to Comparable protocol and many others

Comment: BTW if you need to access the values you just need to convert to NSDecimalNumber

Comment: Why do you think that `<` calls itself?

Comment: Because the app crashed when I used the operator, and the operator function seemed to call itself when I were debugging.